# special attributes in tag that are processed by javascript file

Tags: html

Impress.js supports a number of attributes:

data-x, data-y, data-z will move the slide on the screen in 3D space;

data-rotate, data-rotate-x, data-rotate-y rotate the element around the specified axis (in degrees);

data-scale – enlarges or shrinks the slide.

```
div id="intro" class="step" data-x="0" data-y="0">
<h2>Introducing Galaxy Nexus</h2>
<p>Android 4.0<br /> Super Amoled 720p Screen<br />
<img src="assets/img/nexus_1.jpg" width="232" height="458" alt="Galaxy Nexus" />
```

```
 <!-- We are offsetting the second slide, rotating it and making it 1.8 times larger -->
<div id="simplicity" class="step" data-x="1100" data-y="1200" data-scale="1.8" data-rotate="190">
<h2>Simplicity in Android 4.0</h2>
<p>Android 4.0, Ice Cream Sandwich brings an entirely new look and feel..</p>
<img src="assets/img/nexus_2.jpg" width="289" height="535" alt="Galaxy Nexus" />
```

Impress.js

```
(function ( document, window ) {
'use strict';

// HELPER FUNCTIONS

var pfx = (function () {

    var style = document.createElement('dummy').style,
        prefixes = 'Webkit Moz O ms Khtml'.split(' '),
        memory = {};

    return function ( prop ) {
        if ( typeof memory[ prop ] === "undefined" ) {

            var ucProp  = prop.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + prop.substr(1),
                props   = (prop + ' ' + prefixes.join(ucProp + ' ') + ucProp).split(' ');

            memory[ prop ] = null;
            for ( var i in props ) {
                if ( style[ props[i] ] !== undefined ) {
                    memory[ prop ] = props[i];
                    break;
                }
            }

        }

        return memory[ prop ];
    }

})();

var arrayify = function ( a ) {
    return [].slice.call( a );
};

var css = function ( el, props ) {
    var key, pkey;
    for ( key in props ) {
        if ( props.hasOwnProperty(key) ) {
            pkey = pfx(key);
            if ( pkey != null ) {
                el.style[pkey] = props[key];
            }
        }
    }
    return el;
}

var byId = function ( id ) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

var $ = function ( selector, context ) {
    context = context || document;
    return context.querySelector(selector);
};

var $$ = function ( selector, context ) {
    context = context || document;
    return arrayify( context.querySelectorAll(selector) );
};

var translate = function ( t ) {
    return " translate3d(" + t.x + "px," + t.y + "px," + t.z + "px) ";
};

var rotate = function ( r, revert ) {
    var rX = " rotateX(" + r.x + "deg) ",
        rY = " rotateY(" + r.y + "deg) ",
        rZ = " rotateZ(" + r.z + "deg) ";

    return revert ? rZ+rY+rX : rX+rY+rZ;
};

var scale = function ( s ) {
    return " scale(" + s + ") ";
};

var getElementFromUrl = function () {
    // get id from url # by removing `#` or `#/` from the beginning,
    // so both "fallback" `#slide-id` and "enhanced" `#/slide-id` will work
    return byId( window.location.hash.replace(/^#\/?/,"") );
};

// CHECK SUPPORT

var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var impressSupported = ( pfx("perspective") != null ) &&
                       ( document.body.classList ) &&
                       ( document.body.dataset ) &&
                       ( ua.search(/(iphone)|(ipod)|(android)/) == -1 );

var roots = {};

var impress = window.impress = function ( rootId ) {

    rootId = rootId || "impress";

    // if already initialized just return the API
    if (roots["impress-root-" + rootId]) {
        return roots["impress-root-" + rootId];
    }

    // DOM ELEMENTS

    var root = byId( rootId );

    if (!impressSupported) {
        root.className = "impress-not-supported";
        return;
    } else {
        root.className = "";
    }

    // viewport updates for iPad
    var meta = $("meta[name='viewport']") || document.createElement("meta");
    // hardcoding these values looks pretty bad, as they kind of depend on the content
    // so they should be at least configurable
    meta.content = "width=1024, minimum-scale=0.75, maximum-scale=0.75, user-scalable=no";
    if (meta.parentNode != document.head) {
        meta.name = 'viewport';
        document.head.appendChild(meta);
    }

    var canvas = document.createElement("div");
    canvas.className = "canvas";

    arrayify( root.childNodes ).forEach(function ( el ) {
        canvas.appendChild( el );
    });
    root.appendChild(canvas);

    var steps = $$(".step", root);

    // SETUP
    // set initial values and defaults

    document.documentElement.style.height = "100%";

    css(document.body, {
        height: "100%",
        overflow: "hidden"
    });

    var props = {
        position: "absolute",
        transformOrigin: "top left",
        transition: "all 0s ease-in-out",
        transformStyle: "preserve-3d"
    }

    css(root, props);
    css(root, {
        top: "50%",
        left: "50%",
        perspective: "1000px"
    });
    css(canvas, props);

    var current = {
        translate: { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 },
        rotate:    { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 },
        scale:     1
    };

    var stepData = {};

    var isStep = function ( el ) {
        return !!(el && el.id && stepData["impress-" + el.id]);
    }

    steps.forEach(function ( el, idx ) {
        var data = el.dataset,
            step = {
                translate: {
                    x: data.x || 0,
                    y: data.y || 0,
                    z: data.z || 0
                },
                rotate: {
                    x: data.rotateX || 0,
                    y: data.rotateY || 0,
                    z: data.rotateZ || data.rotate || 0
                },
                scale: data.scale || 1,
                el: el
            };

        if ( !el.id ) {
            el.id = "step-" + (idx + 1);
        }

        stepData["impress-" + el.id] = step;

        css(el, {
            position: "absolute",
            transform: "translate(-50%,-50%)" +
                       translate(step.translate) +
                       rotate(step.rotate) +
                       scale(step.scale),
            transformStyle: "preserve-3d"
        });

    });

    // making given step active

    var active = null;
    var hashTimeout = null;

    var goto = function ( el ) {
        if ( !isStep(el) || el == active) {
            // selected element is not defined as step or is already active
            return false;
        }

        // Sometimes it's possible to trigger focus on first link with some keyboard action.
        // Browser in such a case tries to scroll the page to make this element visible
        // (even that body overflow is set to hidden) and it breaks our careful positioning.
        //
        // So, as a lousy (and lazy) workaround we will make the page scroll back to the top
        // whenever slide is selected
        //
        // If you are reading this and know any better way to handle it, I'll be glad to hear about it!
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);

        var step = stepData["impress-" + el.id];

        if ( active ) {
            active.classList.remove("active");
        }
        el.classList.add("active");

        root.className = "step-" + el.id;

        // `#/step-id` is used instead of `#step-id` to prevent default browser
        // scrolling to element in hash
        //
        // and it has to be set after animation finishes, because in chrome it
        // causes transtion being laggy
        window.clearTimeout( hashTimeout );
        hashTimeout = window.setTimeout(function () {
            window.location.hash = "#/" + el.id;
        }, 1000);

        var target = {
            rotate: {
                x: -parseInt(step.rotate.x, 10),
                y: -parseInt(step.rotate.y, 10),
                z: -parseInt(step.rotate.z, 10)
            },
            translate: {
                x: -step.translate.x,
                y: -step.translate.y,
                z: -step.translate.z
            },
            scale: 1 / parseFloat(step.scale)
        };

        // check if the transition is zooming in or not
        var zoomin = target.scale >= current.scale;

        // if presentation starts (nothing is active yet)
        // don't animate (set duration to 0)
        var duration = (active) ? "1s" : "0";

        css(root, {
            // to keep the perspective look similar for different scales
            // we need to 'scale' the perspective, too
            perspective: step.scale * 1000 + "px",
            transform: scale(target.scale),
            transitionDuration: duration,
            transitionDelay: (zoomin ? "500ms" : "0ms")
        });

        css(canvas, {
            transform: rotate(target.rotate, true) + translate(target.translate),
            transitionDuration: duration,
            transitionDelay: (zoomin ? "0ms" : "500ms")
        });

        current = target;
        active = el;

        return el;
    };

    var prev = function () {
        var prev = steps.indexOf( active ) - 1;
        prev = prev >= 0 ? steps[ prev ] : steps[ steps.length-1 ];

        return goto(prev);
    };

    var next = function () {
        var next = steps.indexOf( active ) + 1;
        next = next < steps.length ? steps[ next ] : steps[ 0 ];

        return goto(next);
    };

    window.addEventListener("hashchange", function () {
        goto( getElementFromUrl() );
    }, false);

    window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function () {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }, false);

    // START 
    // by selecting step defined in url or first step of the presentation
    goto(getElementFromUrl() || steps[0]);

    return (roots[ "impress-root-" + rootId ] = {
        goto: goto,
        next: next,
        prev: prev
    });

}
```

})(document, window);

// EVENTS

(function ( document, window ) {
    'use strict';

```
// keyboard navigation handler
document.addEventListener("keydown", function ( event ) {
    if ( event.keyCode == 9 || ( event.keyCode >= 32 && event.keyCode <= 34 ) || (event.keyCode >= 37 && event.keyCode <= 40) ) {
        switch( event.keyCode ) {
            case 33: ; // pg up
            case 37: ; // left
            case 38:   // up
                     impress().prev();
                     break;
            case 9:  ; // tab
            case 32: ; // space
            case 34: ; // pg down
            case 39: ; // right
            case 40:   // down
                     impress().next();
                     break;
        }

        event.preventDefault();
    }
}, false);

// delegated handler for clicking on the links to presentation steps
document.addEventListener("click", function ( event ) {
    // event delegation with "bubbling"
    // check if event target (or any of its parents is a link)
    var target = event.target;
    while ( (target.tagName != "A") &&
            (target != document.body) ) {
        target = target.parentNode;
    }

    if ( target.tagName == "A" ) {
        var href = target.getAttribute("href");

        // if it's a link to presentation step, target this step
        if ( href && href[0] == '#' ) {
            target = document.getElementById( href.slice(1) );
        }
    }

    if ( impress().goto(target) ) {
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}, false);

// delegated handler for clicking on step elements
document.addEventListener("click", function ( event ) {
    var target = event.target;
    // find closest step element
    while ( !target.classList.contains("step") &&
            (target != document.body) ) {
        target = target.parentNode;
    }

    if ( impress().goto(target) ) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}, false);

// touch handler to detect taps on the left and right side of the screen
document.addEventListener("touchstart", function ( event ) {
    if (event.touches.length === 1) {
        var x = event.touches[0].clientX,
            width = window.innerWidth * 0.3,
            result = null;

        if ( x < width ) {
            result = impress().prev();
        } else if ( x > window.innerWidth - width ) {
            result = impress().next();
        }

        if (result) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}, false);
```

})(document, window);

My question is the Impress.js supposedly to process the data-x, data-y, data-scale attribute of the div tag.     But I don't see where the code in Impress.js is doing that. Can someone point it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [intro to datasets](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/an-introduction-to-datasets/) may help.

First this part checking support for .dataset:

```
// CHECK SUPPORT

var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var impressSupported = ( pfx("perspective") != null ) &&
                       ( document.body.classList ) &&
                       ( document.body.dataset ) &&
                       ( ua.search(/(iphone)|(ipod)|(android)/) == -1 );
```

Then this part of the code, about halfway down:

```
steps.forEach(function ( el, idx ) {
        var data = el.dataset,
            step = {
                translate: {
                    x: data.x || 0,
                    y: data.y || 0,
                    z: data.z || 0
                },
                rotate: {
                    x: data.rotateX || 0,
                    y: data.rotateY || 0,
                    z: data.rotateZ || data.rotate || 0
                },
                scale: data.scale || 1,
                el: el
            };
```